# c++ Define a set of probability distributions in loop

Tags: c++, loops, random

I would like to create a set of normal distribution with different means. 
like this:

```
#include <random>
using namespace std;
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::normal_distribution<double> normal_1(0.0,std_1);
std::normal_distribution<double> normal_2(0.0,std_2);
// and so on until:
std::normal_distribution<double> normal_N(0.0,std_N);
```

I need to be able to change the total number of distributions so a loop will work better, like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i<=N; i++){
std::normal_distribution<double> normal_i(0.0,std_i);
}
```

PD: I'm new to C++, so maybe this is a very basic question.

Comment: [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to the rescue.

Comment: great, it works. Should I post the solution? or remove the question?

Answer (score 1):

As freakish pointed out in a comment, [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) do the job.

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
default_random_engine generator;


int main()
{
    vector<normal_distribution<double>> v = {};

    for (int i=1; i<=N; i++)
    {
        v.push_back(normal_distribution<double> (0.0,std_i));
    }
    //v[i-1](generator); generate a random number from the distribution i
}
```